# Golang, net.TCPConn, SetReadTimeout?

Tags: windows, tcp, timeout, cross-platform, go

I've created a simple Go application on a Mac for writing and reading data to and from a TCP connection. I've used the GAE Go version. Later, I ported that program to Windows, and I got this error :

```
Connection.SetReadTimeout undefined (type *net.TCPConn has no field or method SetReadTimeout)
```

I guess the [net package information on the Golang website](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetReadTimeout) describes the package only for the GAE version. How would I properly set the timeout in a non-GAE Go version?

Answer (score 1):

With latest weekly (aka Go 1 RC2) one has to use the various Set*Deadline methods of the [net.Conn](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) type. Note that the old timeouts were relative to some event, deadlines are absolute times. The background for this change is roughly: setting a [relative] timeout of 1 *s* seems like a good idea in some scenario, but it applied to every event, like receiving a single byte, thus allowing crafted transfers to avoid timeouts forever (with the respective DOS nearby).